# Drawing quarter of a circle in R

Tags: r

I need to draw 90 degrees of a circle in r. I know how to draw a full circle in R with `draw.circle` but I don't know how to hide  270 degrees of it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the package `plotrix`.  Plotrix also has a function `draw.arc`.

```
library(plotrix)
?draw.arc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the package grid, and the function grid.curve.

eg.

```
library(grid)
plot.new()
vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=1, height=1)
pushViewport(vp)

grid.curve(0.5,0.5,0.3,0.3, curvature=arcCurvature(90),square=F,ncp=10)
```